# canonicalize file path strings in TeX

Tags: strings, xstring

I have a package which recursively loads many little modules (essentially tex files) from relative file paths. As modules may load other modules, I have to be careful not to load modules twice, so I keep a record of the file paths I have loaded. BUT, for this to work I have to canonicalize file names to avoid double loading. So what I really want is a macro `\mod@simpl` that canonicalizes the respective strings by eliminating any occurrences of `foo/..`. I have been able to do that for one level (the code is so ugly that I do not want to include it here; there must be a better way) but not for two. I also looked at the `xstring` package, but that does not help either. The table below is my testing table.

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
  source       & result                          & should be \\\hline\hline
  aaa            & \mod@simpl{aaa}            &  aaa\\\hline
  ../../aaa      & \mod@simpl{../../aaa}      &  ../../aaa\\\hline
  aaa/bbb        & \mod@simpl{aaa/bbb}        & aaa/bbb\\\hline
  aaa/..         & \mod@simpl{aaa/..}         & \\\hline
  ../../aaa/bbb  & \mod@simpl{../../aaa/bbb}  & ../../aaa/bbb\\\hline
  ../aaa/../bbb  & \mod@simpl{../aaa/../bbb}  &  ../bbb\\\hline
  ../aaa/bbb     & \mod@simpl{../aaa/bbb}     &  ../aaa/bbb\\\hline
  aaa/bbb/../ddd & \mod@simpl{aaa/bbb/../ddd} & aaa/ddd\\\hline
  aaa/bbb/../..  & \mod@simpl{aaa/bbb/../..}  & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Please help.

Michael

Answer (score 3):

Because LaTeX packages are mentioned and used, I assume the package is a LaTeX package.
If you want to install the package in a TDS compliant tree, the file names of the modules
must be unique, see [TDS specification, "2.4 Duplicate filenames"](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/tds/tds.pdf#page=4):

> Names of TEX input files must be unique within each first-level
>   subdirectory of `texmf/tex` and `texmf/tex/generic`, [...]

Also modern TeX distributions support the search in subdirectories since many years.
There is no need to specify the directories for finding the modules.

Then, with unique file names, you can use LaTeX for the module management. Modules in LaTeX are packages. LaTeX does not load a package file twice. At the second loading request it only checks the options. It triggers errors/warnings in the following cases:

- The requested file name (`\RequirePackage` or `\usepackage`) differs from the provided file name (`\ProvidesPackage` inside the file).
- Later requests come with options that are not present at the first package loading.
- Version management: The date provided in the package (`\ProvidesPackage`) is older than the date in the final optional argument of `\RequirePackage` or `\usepackage`.

Example for module `moda` and package `pkg`. The file name of the module would be
`pkg-moda.sty`. It contains the line, e.g.:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pkg-moda}[2012/10/06 v2.4 Module moda for package pkg]
```

This module is then loaded in other modules or the package via:

```
\RequirePackage{pkg-moda}
```

Then LaTeX will load the module the first time only.

If the module should require a certain version, the date can be added:

```
\RequirePackage{pkg-moda}[2012/10/06]
```

or

```
\RequirePackage{pkg-moda}[2010/06/01]
```

if the versions of `pkg-moda` since 2010/06/01 implements the needed features.

### plain TeX

LaTeX's package management is not provided by plain TeX.
There each module can define a marker that is checked at the beginning of module loading:

```
% File: pkg-moda.sty
\expandafter\ifx\csname ver@pkg-moda.sty\endcsname\relax
\else
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi
\expandafter\def\csname ver@pkg-moda.sty\endcsname{2012/10/06}
```

- The extension of the file name does not matter. I have used `.sty` because 
  many of my LaTeX packages can also be loaded by plain TeX (or even iniTeX),
  the extension comes from the LaTeX requirements for a package.
- The marker can be anything, a command that is exclusively defined by the module,
  a register that is exclusively allocated by the module, …

  In the example above I have used the LaTeX convention:
  `\ver@<filename>` is either the empty macro:

  ```
  \expandafter\def\csname ver@<filename>\endcsname{}
  ```

  or it contains the date in form of `YYYY/MM/DD`, optionally followed by a space and
  a version number and a description.

The first check at the beginning of the file stops the further loading of the module, if the marker is already defined.

Also the check can be added before loading the module, e.g.:

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname ver@pkg-moda.sty\endcsname\relax
  \input pkg-moda.sty\relax
\fi
```

Then the module file is not even opened, when it is already loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation (which I actually was aware of). I had indeed thougth about using (or adapting) the `\usepackage` code from the LaTeX kernel, but decided that it would not use it for my problem. I should probably have made it more clear that my modules are not LaTeX packages, in particular there can be multiple modules in one file, thus one of the basic assumptions fails. I am pretty sure that I have to remember (and compare) canonicalized files paths. But Bruno's answer helps me with this.

Comment: I have a section about plain TeX in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Heiko has answered on how to manage a situation such as the one you describe.  Indeed, letting each small file define one macro to indicate that it has been loaded is the best solution.  I will answer on how to remove `aaa/..` from a string to make it canonical.

EDIT: egreg mentions that my solution was wrong: the regex I used did not do what I claimed.  This should now be fixed.  Also, I had done a half-hearted attempt at supporting Windows, I now decided to leave this as an exercise to the reader.

(Explanations below.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l__kohlhase_str
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mod@simpl #1
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l__kohlhase_str {/#1/}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { /\./ } { / } \l__kohlhase_str
    \kohlhase_aux:N \l__kohlhase_str
    \str_substr:Nnn \l__kohlhase_str { 2 } { -2 }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kohlhase_aux:N #1
  {
    \regex_replace_all:nnNT
      {
        /
          ( [^/.]
          | [^/.][^/]
          | [^/][^/.]
          | [^/]{3,}
          )
        / \.\. /
      }
      { / }
      #1
      { \kohlhase_aux:N #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
  source       & result                          & should be \\\hline\hline
  aaa            & \mod@simpl{aaa}            &  aaa\\\hline
  ../../aaa      & \mod@simpl{../../aaa}      &  ../../aaa\\\hline
  aaa/bbb        & \mod@simpl{aaa/bbb}        & aaa/bbb\\\hline
  aaa/..         & \mod@simpl{aaa/..}         & \\\hline
  ../../aaa/bbb  & \mod@simpl{../../aaa/bbb}  & ../../aaa/bbb\\\hline
  ../aaa/../bbb  & \mod@simpl{../aaa/../bbb}  &  ../bbb\\\hline
  ../aaa/bbb     & \mod@simpl{../aaa/bbb}     &  ../aaa/bbb\\\hline
  aaa/bbb/../ddd & \mod@simpl{aaa/bbb/../ddd} & aaa/ddd\\\hline
  aaa/bbb/../..  & \mod@simpl{aaa/bbb/../..}  & \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The main ingredient is to use LaTeX3's regex module to turn `/aaa/../` to `/`, recursively (see the call to `\kohlhase_aux:N` if the patern has matched: `T`rue argument of `\regex_replace_all:nnNT`).  What is the correct pattern for `aaa`?  The pattern `[^/]+` would almost do, but we do not want to replace `/../../` to `/`, so we work a bit harder.  Doing this, we soon realize that a leading or trailing pattern of `aaa/..` would be missed, so we first prepend and append `/` before doing the replacement.  As an added bonus, I change `/./` to `/` since `.` stands for the current directory in Unix.  At the end, remove the leading and trailing `/` (the string may contain a single `/` before that step) by keeping a substring only.

Comment: How wonderful, there is a regexp package in LaTeX, this will help me tremendously. I am sure that I can extend the actual regexp.

Comment: It's more complicated than that: the last example should resolve to the empty string, for instance.

Comment: you are right, the problem is context-sensitive,  since you need to balance pairs of directory names and "go up" statements `/..`. I guess I will need to have some kind of loop that makes replacements until nothing changes any more. I will post the answer when I have one.

Comment: @egreg I included a loop: if the pattern was found, call the auxiliary `\kohlhase_aux:N` again.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Sorry, but it doesn't produce the required result: just check the table. Leading `../` should be stripped in advance and stored away; in what remains, consecutive `../` must remove the same number of directory names above them, but recursively until no `../` remains.

Comment: @egreg: You are right that my code is wrong.  Would the following work: (1) prepend and append `/`, (2) replace any `/` followed by arbitrary non-`/`-characters (other than `..` or `.`), followed by `/../` by a single `/`, recursively, until that pattern doesn't appear, (3) trim leading and trailing `/`?

Comment: This may possibly be the right way.

Comment: @egreg Fixed.  Another solution would be to split the path at each `/` into a sequence, then loop through that sequence, building a new one, where each `..` pops the new sequence (unless the new sequence is empty, in which case we decrement a counter keeping track of how far back in the original path we went).  At the end, combine the new sequence into a path.  Not sure which approach would be clearer.